# Error When Testing threading Module

Tags: python, multithreading

I am looking to implement the threading module (python3), and wanted to test it out first to see how it could help reduce runtime. The following code does not implement multithreading:

```
import threading, time
import queue
q = queue.Queue(10000000)

def fill_list():
    global q
    while True:
        q.put(1)
        if q.qsize() == 10000000:
            return

t1 = time.clock()
fill_list()
tend = time.clock() - t1

print(tend)
```

This produces:

```
>>>
29.939367999999998
>>>
```

Then I tried to complete the same task with 2 threads in an effort to decrease run time.

```
import threading, time
import queue

q = queue.Queue(10000000)

def fill_list():
    global q 
    while True:
        q.put(1)
        if q.qsize() == 10000000:
            return

t1 = time.clock()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=fill_list, args=())
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=fill_list, args=())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
tend = time.clock() - t1
print(q.qsize())
print(tend)
```

This produces:

```
>>> 
13722
0.018415999999999988
>>>
```

So it completed faster, but it did not actually complete the task of filling up the queue to 10000000. I don't understand why the method would return if the conditional has not been met.

Am I implementing the threading module incorrectly? Is it a problem that the two threads are trying to access the same queue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the threads to finish, as is your main continues execution while the 2 threads are still running.

Add this to fix it.

```
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
tend = time.clock() - t1
```

Comment: Hmm now it seems to be hanging. When I change it from a queue to a list though it works.